# Dynamically set line & paragraph spacings relative to current font-size

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, typography, line-spacing, setspace

I am writing my PhD thesis using the basic `report` class because my advisor asked me to keep it simple and avoid KOMA-classes/memoir for now.

At the moment, I am using the `setspace` package to set my linespacing to `\onehalfspacing` (which I understand is 150% of the text font size). For spacing between paragraphs, I have hard-coded it using `\setlength{\parskip}{0.9em}`. This seemed reasonable to my eyes until my advisor asked to change my text font to 11pt which messed up all manually-tuned spacing.

To avoid such issues in the future, I wish to use the dynamic computation of line and paragraph spacing advised in [this blog article](https://medium.com/@lukejones/3-typography-tips-for-a-more-comfortable-read-fed478affa8d).

How can I set a) my line-spacing to say 175% of the text font size, and b) my paragraph spacing to be same as my text font size (is this a good idea?)

Comment: Please advise if you set `\parindent` to 0pt, i.e., to no indentation at all at the start of each paragraph. (Usually, it's neither necessary nor advisable to set `parskip` to non-zero length unless `\parindent` has been set to 0.)

Comment: I am not doing any particular setting of ```\parindent```.

Comment: Since you have a positive value for `\parindent`, there's really no need to set `\parskip` to some positive value. Really. (The blog post you refernenced has set `\parindent` to zero; if it weren't for that feature, there'd be no reason to make `\parskip` nonzero.)

Comment: @Mico only the first paragraph within each section is __not__ indented.  So, I can pretty much ignore everything in that blog post?

Comment: I'd certainly ignore most everything in that blog post, especially as much of it borders on the trivial ("make the font size of chapter and section headers larger than the main font size" -- wow, what an insight...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the moment, I am using the setspace package to set my linespacing to \onehalfspacing (which I understand is 150% of the text font size).

Not quite. Since your document font size is 11pt, the `setspace` package executes the instruction `\setstretch{1.213}` when reacting to package option `onehalfspacing`. If you're using any kind of standard font, the default value of `\baselineskip` is `1.2`, meaning that the default distance between consecutive text lines is already 20% more than the nominal font size. The product of `1.2` and `1.213` is `1.4556`, which isn't quite equal to `1.5` (150%). If the space between consecutive lines must be exactly 150% of the basic font size, you should (a) not provide the `onehalfspacing` option and (b) issue the instruction `\setstretch{1.25}` (since `1.2*1.25=1.50`). Or, if the line spacing must be 175% of the nominal font size, issue the instruction `\setstretch{1.4583}` (since `1.2*1.4583=1.75`).

These calculations assume that the standard value of `\baselineskip` (which corresponds to "singlespacing") is indeed 120% of the nominal font size. If you're using a highly unusual font, this may not be the case. Please advise if you're using anything but a fairly standard font.

If the value of `\parskip` *must* be nonzero -- and, judging from the comments you posted, it doesn't have to be nonzero -- you may want to start with `\setlength\parskip{1\baselineskip}`. That way, the blank space between paragraphs will correspond to exactly one blank line of text. But, unless your university regulations for you to change the value of `\parskip`, I wouldn't touch this parameter.

Comment: thank you for the wonderfully detailed answer. "If you're using any kind of standard font ....".  I am using ```Libertinus``` for text and unicode-math, I assume this is a non-standard font (as in not conforming to the NFSS)? Hopefully, this calculation using ```\baselineskip``` value of 1.2 holds good for this font too.

Comment: @Krishna - If don't seem to have a font called `Libertinus` on my system. But if this font is at all similar to `Linux Libertine O`, the assumption that the default baselineskip is 120% of the basic font size is indeed valid.

Comment: Yes. Indeed, libertinus is a fork of Linux Libertine, and is available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertinus?lang=en) and on TL since 2017. Thank you for your answer. Much helps. I shall try to go with 175%. Hope that is not a bad choice for a thesis.

Comment: @Krishna - The number one rule (and only rule, really) when it comes to setting the layout of a thesis document is: Obey *all* formal formatting requirements provided by your university, no matter how ugly and odd-looking the final outcome.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Thank you for this advice. I checked with the research degrees office and they confirmed that beyond enforcing word limits, the university allows students full freedom in formatting their theses.

Comment: @Krishna - Wow, you're very fortunate. Just choose sensible defaults and whack away, i.e., write a great thesis! :-)